# React Native project getting Typescript prop error for component that is defined to accept the prop

Tags: typescript, react-native

I've initialised a fresh install of React Native, Typescript and Google Maps. However, with a minimal example as shown below, I'm receiving an error I think I shouldn't be receiving, since MapView should accept the `style: any` prop.

This example uses `react-native-maps` but I'm hoping that this can shed light into how Typescript in general works.

Here are my `package.json`, `tsconfig.json`, and `tslint.json` files:
https://gist.github.com/the-joat/43b1c371424ef5d2195f4ec52e99c5ea

Screenshots:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4J2u.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJqEC.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2XZz.png

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you should be able to use the `customMapStyle` prop, you can generate a style [here](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/)

If you want to achieve a style to the container of the map, you may want to wrap it with a view

Comment: Thanks for the link. I didn't know about that before. But, I think it's just weird that the style prop is declared for that component but Typescript is throwing an error. It's not a matter of really styling the component, but ultimately Typescript's behavior.